# What is the difference between dual degree, 2 Bachelors and double major?

Tags: university, undergraduate

We are considering to offer double majors between my department and other departments. While looking at examples from other universities, we came across other terms such as dual degree.

On the undergraduate level what is the difference, generally speaking, between:

- Double Major
- Dual Degree
- Two Bachelors

Moa

Comment: The [Double Degree (Dual Degree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_degree) wiki page has some explanation about the difference between double degree and double major. I don't know how accurate it is, though. Thanks for asking this question. I didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that:

**Double Degree** often means you get two full Bachelors degrees, which may be from two *different* universities, in two entirely unrelated subject areas. Often these programs are designed to be completed in 5--6 years total. I have also sometimes seen it used with reference to graduate programs. For example, a double degree Masters/PhD program, though this is rarer in my experience.

**Double Major** means you get a single degree from one university, but with a speciality in two related subject areas. For example, you could be a Physics/Chemistry double major. Typically this means you satisfy the core requirements of both programs, possibly using the electives of one to fill in the core of the other.

**Two Bachelors** means you get two full Bachelors degrees. Sometimes this is used as a synonym for a Double Degree, sometimes it is differentiated by requiring that both degrees be granted by the same institution.

Comment: I would have supposed things would be the other way around for 'double degree' and 'two bachelors' with regard to getting them from the same university or not.

Comment: a double degree doesn't have to mean 2 Ba degrees. It could be a PhD in computational physics and a Ba in CS for example (can imagine one engaging in CS work to gain knowledge required to create complex computer simulations or computer controlled lab setups).